# Clicking an item in zoomed in view takes me to another page. But navigating back again does not work

Tags: c#, semantic-zoom

I am making an app in C# that uses Semantic Zoom. I have copied the code from an MS sample called BookStore2Universal_10 and I have made some adjustmens to it. 
My intention is to click an item in the Zoomed in view. Depending on which item I clicked I want another page to open that downloads and displays a file from the internet.
I've succeeded to navigate to this other page but when I navigate back to the zoomed out view and try to click on another item then the program crashes.
I don't know how remedy this problem. I'm grateful for any help you can provide. Please let me know if you need more details.

This code acts on the item clicked

```
private void GridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    BookSku item = (e.ClickedItem as BookSku);
    ((Frame)Window.Current.Content).Navigate(typeof(Stations));
 }
```

With the code below I want to get back to the semantic zoom page.
But I don't know how I should navigate back. It seems to me that the
program tries to initialize again and thereby just crashes no matter which 
panel name I use instead of the question mark.

```
private void BackButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((Frame)Window.Current.Content).Navigate(typeof(?));
}
```

I expect to get back to the zoomed out panel, which I do, and continue    selecting another item. But instead this error message appears:

An unhandled win32 exception occurred in BookStore2Universal_10.exe [4020]